# Ember Not Initializing Store Properly: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

All my versions:

```
Ember: 1.9.0
Handlebars: 2.0.0
jQuery: 2.1.3
Ember Data: 1.0.0-beta.12
```

All I'm trying to do is make a simple Ember Data `store.find()` call and everything seems to be going horribly wrong. **It gets even weirder too. If I wrap `this.store.find(...)` in a `get()` call and instead say `this.get('store').find(...)` I get a completely different error.**

Here's the error I'm getting with just `this.store.find(...)`:

```
Error while processing route: budget Cannot read property 'find' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
at Application.BudgetRoute.Ember.Route.extend.model (http://localhost/javascript/app/routes/budget.route.js:9:24)
at EmberObject.extend.deserialize (http://localhost/javascript/bower_components/ember/ember.js:24849:21)
at applyHook (http://localhost/javascript/bower_components/ember/ember.js:47575:30)
at Object.HandlerInfo.runSharedModelHook (http://localhost/javascript/bower_components/ember/ember.js:45596:22)
at Object.subclass.getModel (http://localhost/javascript/bower_components/ember/ember.js:45822:21)
at __exports__.bind (http://localhost/javascript/bower_components/ember/ember.js:47449:19)
at tryCatch (http://localhost/javascript/bower_components/ember/ember.js:47898:16)
at invokeCallback (http://localhost/javascript/bower_components/ember/ember.js:47910:17)
at publish (http://localhost/javascript/bower_components/ember/ember.js:47881:11)
at http://localhost/javascript/bower_components/ember/ember.js:29453:9
```

`this.store` is undefined here.

Here's the error I'm getting with `this.get('store').find(...)`:

```
Error while processing route: budget Assertion Failed: Budget has no method `find`. Error: Assertion Failed: Budget has no method `find`.
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.EmberError (http://localhost/javascript/bower_components/ember/ember.js:13740:23)
    at Object.Ember.assert (http://localhost/javascript/bower_components/ember/ember.js:3902:15)
    at Object.EmberObject.extend.store.computed.find (http://localhost/javascript/bower_components/ember/ember.js:24892:19)
    at Application.BudgetRoute.Ember.Route.extend.model (http://localhost/javascript/app/routes/budget.route.js:9:32)
    at EmberObject.extend.deserialize (http://localhost/javascript/bower_components/ember/ember.js:24849:21)
    at applyHook (http://localhost/javascript/bower_components/ember/ember.js:47575:30)
    at Object.HandlerInfo.runSharedModelHook (http://localhost/javascript/bower_components/ember/ember.js:45596:22)
    at Object.subclass.getModel (http://localhost/javascript/bower_components/ember/ember.js:45822:21)
    at __exports__.bind (http://localhost/javascript/bower_components/ember/ember.js:47449:19)
```

This time it finds this.store, but the Budget model has no `find()` method on it (and no where on the internet are there instructions that say there should be...)

budget.route.js:

```
define([
  'ember',
  'application',
  'controllers/budget.controller',
  'views/budget.view'
], function(Ember, Application) {
  Application.BudgetRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
      return this.store.find('budget', params.budget_key);
    }
  });

  return Application.BudgetRoute;
});
```

My Budget model:

```
define([
  'ember-data',
  'application'
], function(DS, Application) {
  Application.Budget = DS.Model.extend({
    budget_key: DS.attr(),
    user: DS.attr(),
    title: DS.attr(),
    description: DS.attr(),
    picture: DS.attr(),
    order: DS.attr(),
    created: DS.attr()
  });

  return Application.Budget;
});
```

My ApplicationAdapter:

```
define([
  'ember-data',
  'application',
  'models/budget'
], function(DS, Application) {
  Application.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api'
  });

  return Application.ApplicationAdapter;
});
```

**I'm also using `deferReadiness()` and `advanceReadiness()` if that makes any difference here...**

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing this as well with 1.9.0. Seems that the store is never set up at all, `MyApp.__container__.lookup("store:main")` is `undefined`. I spent some time trying to track this down but I think it could be a major rabbit hole and I didn't find any answers.

`1.10.0-beta.1` seems to be working however. I know that's not really an answer to your specific question but I hope it's better than nothing in this situation.

Comment: I tried downgrading to Ember-Data beta.1 and it didn't help. Which versions of Ember and Ember-Data were you referring to?

Comment: Here is what I got that ended up working, but I don't think the problem is with Ember-Data---

Ember      : 1.9.0
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.12
Handlebars : 2.0.0
jQuery     : 1.11.2

Comment: Hmmm those are the exact versions I have too. No luck though. Where were you able to make this work? Is it online?

Comment: Yea it works, but I did run in to plenty of trouble getting handlebars to work with ember cli and `emblem`. Do you mean that you still have an undefined store after using 1.9.0? I never got that error again myself after 1.9.0.

Comment: Hmmm I'm not using ember CLI, just vanilla ember and requirejs for now. Could that be the problem? I've tried every version combination I could think of. Nothing has worked. Another thing is that I'm not actually explicitly declaring my store anywhere because ember is supposed to do it for me. Do I need to do that?

Comment: Probably not a requirejs problem. I would only suggest try checking for cached dependencies that shouldn't be. That's all I got.

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks for your help. I'm still not getting anywhere. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: @SunjayVarma did you ever figure this out? I'm currently having the same problem.

Comment: @Mickelain unfortunately, no. I had to switch to ember cli and port my entire project. That wasn't so bad except for the problem with running ember cli on windows. Its build is extremely slow (even for small projects) - 2-3 minutes for every change you make. I eventually ended up completely abandoning ember because of this.

Comment: If ember is your only option and you're not on windows, I recommend going with porting it to ember cli. That's the recommended way to write ember apps now.